# How do I make the uploaded file have a random name?

Tags: php, image, upload

I am wondering how to make the image I have uploaded have a random name.
Using this, I can get a random string:

```
    <?php
    function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
    }

    echo  generateRandomString();  // OR: generateRandomString(24)
```

And I use this to upload it:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "bmp" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, BMP & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo '<br>The file <img src="http://upimg.comxa.com/uploads/'. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). '"> has been uploaded.';
        echo '<br>Direct URL: http://upimg.comxa.com/uploads/'. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is I don't know how.
I copied the code from w3schools, so I don't know entirely how it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Generate some UUID, there is a lot of solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your function to change the variable $target_file, as this is where the file is saved.

So instead of this on line 2:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Replace it with this:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . generateRandomString();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it says it was uploaded but when I view the uploads/ directory, it isn't there.

Comment: This could be because I forgot the file extension now isn't added.

Answer (score 1):

Get each character by array variable

```
<?php

function rndStr(){
$characters = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","Z","Y","Z");

//generate 6 characters from it 
$charI = rand(0,25);
$charII = rand(0,25);
$charIII = rand(0,25);
$charIV = rand(0,25);
$charV = rand(0,25);
$charVI = rand(0,25);

//output as string
$rnd_name = $characters[$charI].$characters[$charII].$characters[$charIII].$characters[$charIV].$characters[$charV].$characters[$charVI] ; 
return $rnd_name;
}
```

Usage

```
$target_file = $target_dir . rndStr();
```